# Reading table names from content of MySQL files

Tags: mysql

My hard drive was unclean closed and all of my files was moved by fsck into lost&found directory without original names. Unfortunatelly, I had no backup of every database. I'm sure I can detect extensions based on size of files. Is it possible to restore somehow table names from content of mysql files (both MyISAM and InnoDB)? Then I could restore original file names. I use MySQL 5.7.